# Avoid copying with reinterpret_cast the buffer?

Tags: c++, memcpy, reinterpret-cast

I came across a code snippet where the bytes from a buffer were copied into a struct variable using `memcpy()`:

```
MtaHeader m_hdr;
memcpy(&m_hdr,&p_data[position],sizeof(MtaHeader));
```

I changed it to:

```
MtaHeader* m_hdr = reinterpret_cast<MtaHeader*>(&p_data[position]);
```

My aim was to avoid copying of buffered data from `p_data` into local variable `m_hdr`, instead just make an `MtaHeader*` pointer point to the `p_data`.

Is what I did correct, and did I make the code faster? Will the elements of the struct get correct values?

On the other hand, if I want to copy the buffer data to a local variable, is there any better way than `memcpy()` in this case?

Comment: In what way(s) does `memcpy` need to be improved?

Comment: Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish with these copy/cast codes, how can one say if either is "correct"?  And I would imagine that, unless `MtaHeader` is very large, any speed difference would be insignificant.

Comment: Smart compilers will recognize that the `memcpy` is only meant to ensure alignment and bypass the strict aliasing rule, and they will optimize out the actual copy if possible.    (And the cases where they *can't* optimize it out are those where the cast would not have worked in the first place, e.g. because the machine requires alignment which was not ensured.)  So your change will probably not make the code faster.

Comment: There could be issues with the lifetime of the object the pointer refers to. E.g. the following code results in undefined behaviour `auto foo = std::make_unique<int[]>(10); auto bar = foo.get() + 2; foo.reset(); std::cout << *bar;`. We won't be able to tell. if this is the case in your case without more info...

Comment: I prefer `memcpy` method with little changes: `memcpy( &m_hdr, p_data + position, sizeof m_hdr );`. I don't think second method is faster but its readability is worse.

Comment: *"did i make code faster?"* is a question that can only be answered by profiling. Which you should have done *before* deciding to make this change

Comment: You’ve quite possibly made the code slower. Unaligned memory access is going to be slower than aligned access. But even if it were faster, you’ve changed the semantics of the code from value to reference, which depending on the surrounding code can lead to bad consequences. And finally, as has been pointed out, you’ve pushed yourself firmly into UB land and you don’t even know if is actually faster to boot. Revert the change.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest problem here is alignment -- if `position` is such that the resulting pointer is misaligned, using the `reinterpret_cast` and dereferencing the resulting pointer gives undefined behavior.

There's also the issue that `MtaHeader` needs to be *trivially-copyable* or the `memcpy` will not work.

Comment: I would think changes to the original would be as big a problem.

Comment: when you say "position is misaligned", you mean "position" is not pointing at the start point of MtaHeader inside p_data buffer? The MtaHeader is trivially copyable which i made sure.

Comment: I mean the `position` points at an adress in the input buffer that is not correctly aligned for whatever type(s) are inside `MtaHeader`.  For example, if `MtaHeader` contains 64-bit values that require 8 byte alignment, and `&p_data[position]` is not a multiple of 8.

Comment: so if my buffer is an array of uint8_t and MtaHeader is #pragma pack (1) then the UB can be avoided, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your variant, assuming `p_data + position` isn't already pointing to a `MtaHeader` object or an object pointer-interconvertible with such an object (unlikely if that is supposed to be a byte buffer) and when you actually use the resulting pointer to access its members directly, has always undefined behavior.

Depending on the exact details, it may only be "technically" undefined behavior (because of a lack of `std::launder`) and work as expected on most compilers, but in other cases, such as for example if you don't assure that `p_data + position` is properly aligned for `MtaHeader`, it will straight-up result in a compiled program that crashes or misbehaves on common compilers/architectures.

The original version will also be wrong if `MtaHeader` is not trivially-copyable or too large for the buffer bounds. Both can be checked with `static_assert`. In many cases since C++20, the `memcpy` version can be replaced by `std::bit_cast`, which has some more built-in protections regarding these requirements.

Even then it is of course assumed that the buffer actually holds a valid object representation for `MtaHeader`. If the contents of the buffer were not obtained by copying the object representation from a `MtaHeader` in the same program, then there are all sorts of possible representation issues, especially when the data comes from another machine. A common one being for example endianess.

Compilers are often (again depending on the exact circumstances) clever enough to optimize away the copy in the original version if it is not needed.

So in short, don't do that.

Comment: The code is perfectly legal if `p_data` is a `char *`, `signed char*`, `unsigned char*` or `std::byte *` that points to actual objects of type `MtaHeader`. So not always UB. Just UB if `p_data` is some random buffer like we all assume. The real problem here is alignment and that is not just technical but very practical.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yes, ok. My assumption was that `p_data` is not actually pointing to a `MtaHeader` object but to an element some buffer array (or is such an array) of one of the types you listed, because otherwise the whole question would be pretty pointless. Alignment is one of the issues I mean under "exact details" and one of the issues that will fall under "but in other cases" almost always if not taken care of carefully.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, what i did is correct

It depends on `p_data` is, and what `MtaHeader` is. But most likely what you did is not correct and the behviour of the program is undefined. That would be bad.

> if i want to copy the buffer data to local value, is there any better way than memcpy in this case?

In some cases, `std::bit_cast` may be better. But it cannot be used in all cases, and using `std::memcopy` is fine assuming that the preconditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that p_data is some random buffer of data then your solution is both technically and practically wrong. It will fail on every architecture where unaligned access is not handled by the CPU.

The code with `memcpy` is only correct when `MtaHeader` is *trivially-copyable* and the data doesn't need any endian conversion.

To make this always correct you have to extract the data from the buffer byte by byte, recombine them into the proper types and call the constructor for `MtaHeader`. For some types that might mean first shuffeling the bytes to correct for endianess and then `memcpy()` them into variables of the correct type, e.g. for double.

But nobody writes technically correct code for stuff like this. Everybody takes shortcuts and writes practically working code that depends on architecture and/or compiler defined behavior.

Note: a type like double is technically even more complex since you have to deal with `INFINITY` and `NAN` and denormalized numbers that your arch might not even have.

I recommend using an existing framework for stuff like this, like google protobuf if you care about compatibility with other systems.